# Lazy loading in my own WordPress theme

Tags: theme-development

I am designing a theme for WordPress and, as I read in the [official documentation](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/14/lazy-loading-images-in-5-5/), the `loading="lazy"` parameter is added only since WP 5.5 as long as the post images have a defined width and height.

With my template I don't see this parameter being automatically applied. Should I do something in the functions.php file? I am using version 6.4.3.

Thank you very much for the help!!

Comment: This behavior was [later updated in 5.9](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/12/29/enhanced-lazy-loading-performance-in-5-9/), as it turned out unconditionally making images lazy loaded harmed cases where you want images to load quickly, like a page's LCP image. Maybe your images are falling under the updated heuristics?